# How to populate Controller.Request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use the `Request`, `Response` properties of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class to set and read cookies in the HTTP request and response. The reason to do so is - it obviates the need for writing utility classes that read from requests and populate data in some helper class. I can push all such code in custom base controller (from which all my controllers are derived from).

So I have got following code in my `BaseController'

```
if (Request != null)
{
   HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
   if (authCookie != null)
   {
        HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authCookie.Value), null);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.User;
   }
}
```

but the `Request` is always null. How is this populated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this code in the constructor of your base controller then it is normal. You need to put it in the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) method. Also what you are doing shouldn't be done in a controller. Looking at your code you seem to be populating the HttpContext.User property: this should be done in a custom Authorize action filter.

For example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var result = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (result)
        {
            var authCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                httpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authCookie.Value), null);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = httpContext.User;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then decorate your base controller with this attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{}
```

Notice that this attribute requires the user to be authenticated in order to give access to the corresponding action so use it only on controllers/actions that require authentication.

Comment: I have indeed put my code in `Initiaze` method. I also have `MyAuthorizeAttribute`. My problem is with mocking. If I go by your approach I have to mock `HttpContextBase` and then inject it as a dependency (I'm using Moq and StructureMap). I find that particularly challenging. If I use `Controller.HttpContext` or `Controller.Request`, I can easily mock these properties on a controller.

Comment: @Suhas, `HttpContextBase` is passed as argument to the `AuthorizeCore` method. So all you need to do in your unit test is mock it and pass it.